# $\sigma$-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let a measure space be  $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ with $1\leq p_1<p_2<\infty$, then $f \in L^{p_2}$ $\Rightarrow f\in L^{p_1}$.
Give a counterexample to show that this statement does not hold generally when the measure space is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: You define $p$ and do nothing with it afterwards? Moreover how it is stated right now does not make much sense, since there is no relation between $p_1$ and $p_2$, maybe you should specify what $p$ is..

Comment: I am quite confused by your question.  First off, Shashi asks a very good question.  Second, do you mean to say that $(\Omega, \mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$?  If so, you should fix your question.  Finally, is $L_{p}$ the space of $p$-integrable functions, i.e. $\{ f : \int |f|^p < \infty\}$?  If so, the usual convention is to write $L^p$ (with a superscript, rather than a subscript).  If not, what is $L_p$?

Comment: sorry, I was confused. And I also don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $f(x) = |x|^{-a} 1_{|x| \leq 1}$, $g(x) = |x|^{-b} 1_{|x| > 1}$.
$f$ is integrable iff $a < d$ and $g$ is integrable iff $b > d$.
This particular example was taken from Stein & Shakarchi - Real Analysis Chapter 2 Exercise 10. In particular, we can use this example to show that the $L^{p_1}$ and $L^{p_2}$ are not contained in each other.

Comment: Although the title of the question is "$\sigma$-finite", the first sentence in the question says $\mu(\Omega)<\infty.  Depending on what the OP actually means, your answer may or may not be relevant.  (I've voted to close the question as unclear.)

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I interpreted that he was asking.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what the question was (or should have been).